# Pass parameters to sub report in rdlc

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, rdlc

I am trying to pass parameters in a sub report in rdlc report. I have user ReportParameter but when I execute it the function is not called and it show **"Report cannot be shown"**

```
        ReportParameter[] paramReport = new ReportParameter[6];
        paramReport[0] = new ReportParameter("Month1", (DateTime.ParseExact(fromd1.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy"), "dd/MMM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).ToString("MMMM"), false);
        paramReport[1] = new ReportParameter("Month2", (DateTime.ParseExact(fromdate2.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy"), "dd/MMM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).ToString("MMMM"), false);
        paramReport[2] = new ReportParameter("Month3", (DateTime.ParseExact(dt_todate3.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy"), "dd/MMM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).ToString("MMMM"), false);
        paramReport[3] = new ReportParameter("Month4", (DateTime.ParseExact(dt_todate4.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy"), "dd/MMM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).ToString("MMMM"), false);
        paramReport[4] = new ReportParameter("Month5", (DateTime.ParseExact(dt_todate5.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy"), "dd/MMM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).ToString("MMMM"), false);
        paramReport[5] = new ReportParameter("Month6", (DateTime.ParseExact(dt_todate6.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy"), "dd/MMM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).ToString("MMMM"), false);
        this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(paramReport);
        this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

Above is my code where I am passing parameters to the sub report. But this code is not working.

Please if anybody knows how to do this then help me..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things that could go wrong using subreports.

As this [link](http://www.gotreportviewer.com/subreports/) said, there are three common reasons for this error:

1. ReportViewer could not find the .rdlc corresponding to the subreport
2. one or more parameters expected by the subreport were not passed by the main report
3. data for the subreport was not supplied

Possible solutions:

1. put subreport .rdlc file in the same folder as main .rdlc file
2. the code you posted seems correct but you have to previously set subreport parameters in Design View > right click on subreport object > Subreport properties > Parameters; set Parameters value using Expressions or using this syntax: i.e. `[@Month1]`
3. use `SubreportProcessing` event